# ab gives slower response times from origin server than from another server

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, varnish, apachebench

I have varnish running on an AWS EC2 instance.  When I perform 'ab' from that server on a site hosted on itself, I get these results:

```
  50%    393
  66%    439
  75%    457
  80%    476
  90%    519
  95%    583
  98%    643
  99%    676
 100%    744 (longest request)
```

but when i perform 'ab' from a DIFFERENT server, I get these results:

```
  50%    269
  66%    307
  75%    344
  80%    355
  90%    401
  95%    455
  98%    487
  99%    554
 100%    591 (longest request)
```

The difference of ~150ms is pretty consistent.  I wonder what could be happening that would make the request take **longer** directly from the origin server.

Comment: Are you querying the web server or the varnish cache?

Comment: ab https://www.domain.tld/ - so it's hitting apache on 443 as the ssl endpoint, which grabs varnish cache on port 80, which caches from apache on port 8080

Comment: Well, in that case ab probably takes resources from the server when you run it locally or you didn't run the tests properly.